# HTTP 404 ERROR while starting application in cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

hello friends i developed a simple java web application and hosted in vmware cloudfoundry but i am unable to launch my application in the browser . it gives this error

HTTP Status 404 - /

type Status report

message /

description The requested resource (/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

kindly reply me at aravnd8babu@gmail.com

Comment: Hi, does your application work OK locally? Are you using STS?

Comment: hi....i did not run it locally....i am using eclipse jee

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the application URL in your host file? If not add a new entry i.e:
Cloudfoundry-IP applicationName.vcap.me

In your local tomcat the URL is localhost:8080/applicationName but in cloudfoundry it is applicationName.vcap.me

Run the command "vmc apps" and provide the output.

Comment: hello... i am using apache tomcat 6.0.35.....i cant get your suggestion.....i never added my application url in my host file....how to add it? pls help me

Comment: In Windows open the host file in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc . Add an entry for your deployed application in CF i.e.

10.254.241.60 vcap.me api.vcap.me
10.254.241.60 <Application_Name>.vcap.me

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>cd drivers

C:\Windows\System32\drivers>cd etc

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>vmc apps
'vmc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>172.30.49.85 babuincloud.vcap.me
'172.30.49.85' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>172.30.49.85babuincloud.vcap.me
'172.30.49.85babuincloud.vcap.me' is not recognized as an internal or external c
ommand,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>

Comment: i tried like this but failed..... i don know how to register my url....but in c:\windows... path i could see a host file but don know how to register it....so i tries in command prompt but failed.....pls help

Comment: my application name is babuincloud......url running by creating instances is 172.30.49.85

Comment: It seems that vmc isn't installed on your windows machine. Did you install the vmc command line interface?
http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/installing-vmc.html

Comment: Since you are using eclipse for deployment on CloudFoundry you can use the cf-maven-plugin and run the following target: mvn cf:apps